# Trying to pass a Stash variable to a Playa tag

Tags: playa, stash

I want to pass the "series_entry_id" created in the exp:playa:parents tag as the parent_id of the exp:playa:siblings tag, but it is not parsing the "series_entry_id". I am not sure if there is a better, more efficient way of doing this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
{exp:stash:set_list
    name="sermon"
    parse_tags="yes"
    parse_depth="2"
    parse_conditionals="yes"
}

    {exp:channel:entries
        channel="media"
        dynamic="no"
        disable="categories|category_fields|member_data"
        orderby="date"
        url_title="{segment_3}"
        limit="1"
    }

        {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
        {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
        {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
        {stash:speaker}{speaker}{/stash:speaker}
        {stash:description}{description}{/stash:description}
        {stash:vimeo_id}{vimeo_id}{/stash:vimeo_id}
        {stash:message_number}{message_number}{/stash:message_number}
        {stash:transcript_file}{transcript_file}{/stash:transcript_file}
        {stash:transcript_embed}{transcript_embed}{/stash:transcript_embed}
        {stash:entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:entry_date}

        {!-- Get Series Data --}
        {exp:playa:parents channel="sermon_series" limit="1"}
            {stash:series_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:series_entry_id}
            {stash:series_title}{title}{/stash:series_title}
            {stash:series_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:series_url_title}
            {stash:series_graphic}{series_graphic}{/stash:series_graphic}
        {/exp:playa:parents}

        {!-- Get Series Siblings --}
        {exp:stash:set_list:nested
            name="siblings"
            parse_tags="yes"
        }

            {exp:playa:siblings entry_id="{entry_id}" parent_id="{series_entry_id}"}
                {stash:sibling_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:sibling_url_title}
                {stash:sibling_title}{title}{/stash:sibling_title}
                {stash:sibling_entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:sibling_entry_date}
            {/exp:playa:siblings}

        {/exp:stash:set_list:nested}

    {/exp:channel:entries}

{/exp:stash:set_list}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `series_entry_id` variable is not defined at the point you're calling it. Try simplifying by avoiding the nesting. The siblings tag doesn't need to be inside the channel entries tag since you have already stashed the `entry_id` and can use that outside the loop. (Alternatively you might be able to get a quick win with a few well-placed `parse="inward"` parameters, but personally I find them to be too black-magicky). Something like this perhaps:

```
{exp:stash:set_list
 name="sermon"
 parse_tags="yes"
 parse_depth="2"
 parse_conditionals="yes"
}
  {exp:channel:entries
    channel="media"
    dynamic="no"
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data"
    orderby="date"
    url_title="{segment_3}"
    limit="1"
  }
    {stash:entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:entry_id}
    {stash:title}{title}{/stash:title}
    {stash:url_title}{url_title}{/stash:url_title}
    {stash:speaker}{speaker}{/stash:speaker}
    {stash:description}{description}{/stash:description}
    {stash:vimeo_id}{vimeo_id}{/stash:vimeo_id}
    {stash:message_number}{message_number}{/stash:message_number}
    {stash:transcript_file}{transcript_file}{/stash:transcript_file}
    {stash:transcript_embed}{transcript_embed}{/stash:transcript_embed}
    {stash:entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:entry_date}

    {!-- Get Series Data --}
    {exp:playa:parents channel="sermon_series" limit="1"}
        {stash:series_entry_id}{entry_id}{/stash:series_entry_id}
        {stash:series_title}{title}{/stash:series_title}
        {stash:series_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:series_url_title}
        {stash:series_graphic}{series_graphic}{/stash:series_graphic}
    {/exp:playa:parents}

  {/exp:channel:entries}
{/exp:stash:set_list}

{exp:stash:get_list name="sermon"}
    {!-- Get Series Siblings --}
    {exp:stash:set_list
        name="siblings"
        parse_tags="yes"
    }
        {exp:playa:siblings entry_id="{entry_id}" parent_id="{series_entry_id}"}
            {stash:sibling_url_title}{url_title}{/stash:sibling_url_title}
            {stash:sibling_title}{title}{/stash:sibling_title}
            {stash:sibling_entry_date}{entry_date}{/stash:sibling_entry_date}
        {/exp:playa:siblings}

    {/exp:stash:set_list}
{/exp:stash:get_list}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but maybe try a higher `parse_depth` on your very first `{stash:set_list}` tag. Try `parse_depth=3` or `parse_depth=4` maybe?

```
{exp:stash:set_list
  name="sermon"
  parse_tags="yes"
  parse_depth="4"
  parse_conditionals="yes"
}
```

I find I typically have to bump up the `parse_depth` if I'm using a Playa tag in a `channel:entries` tag in Stash.